# What is the relationship between $T:V\to V$, a linear transform and $\wedge^k T:\wedge^kV\to \wedge^k V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here the definition is:
$\wedge^k(T)(v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_k)=T v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge T v_k$.
Does there exist an explicit relationship between the matrix of $T$ and that of $\wedge^k T$?For example, there is a question:

> Suppose that all traces $tr(\wedge^k T)=0$ for all $k=0,1,\cdots,
> > n(=\dim V)$, show that $T$ is nilpotent.

If possible, I hope I could find a reference dealing with this issue.

Comment: Do you know the relation between those $\operatorname{Tr}\left(\wedge^k T\right)$ and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ ? (IIRC this is on math.stackexchange somewhere.)

Comment: No. Would you please tell me where I can find more information about it? Thanks~

Comment: See, e.g., *On the characteristic polynomial* by Patrick da Silva (I can't find a better source than http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=FBECD41AB9D2118B1BB298A92C0DD31F right now).

Comment: Bhatia's Matrix Analysis is another resource that discusses this

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a basis $B=\{b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$ for $V$, then a basis for $\wedge^k V$ is given by $\{ b_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge b_{i_k} \text{ }| \text{ } i_1< \ldots < i_k \}$. It can get messy in general, but you only need to know the diagonal entries for your problem. These can be obtained conveniently if one first chooses $B$ to be the basis that gives the Jordan normal form (so the diagonal entries are precisely the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$).

Hint for the problem: To show that $T$ is nilpotent we just have to show that the characteristic polynomial $(X-\lambda_1)(X- \lambda_2) \cdots (X- \lambda_n)$ is equal to $X^n$. The $X^{n-1}$ coefficient is $-Tr(T)$, so we know that is zero. Can you somehow relate the other coefficients to the traces? (try this by firstly assuming that $T$ is diagonal and $B$ is the basis of eigenvectors... find the corresponding matrix for $\wedge^kT$ w.r.t the basis given above and see if it tells you anything about the other coefficients).